# Looking for a good on-line JS obsfucator for minifying purposes only

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I've seared the web, but these tools, I found and tested, doesn't seems to be enough for me.

- [BrainJar's Chrunchinator](http://www.brainjar.com/js/crunch/demo.html) does a very good (in my opinion) minifying job, but without any code obsfucation,
- [Online JavaScript/CSS Compression](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/), though claims to be doing obsfucation ("Minify only, no symbol obfuscation" checkbox NOT checked) does nothing else, than just minification, sometimes even worse than BrainJar's; don't know why,
- [Free Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) does both minimize + obsfucation, but more like for security purposes (variables and functions have names hard to understand, not minified to shortest possible); it was also marked on some SO question as being not secure enough and it also fails on some a bit more complex JS code (many variables left untouched),
- [Javascript Code Encrypter And Obfuscator](http://www.atasoyweb.net/Javascript_Encrypter/javascript_encrypter_eng.php) does a real good job, but obsfucation is oriented toward security, not minification, so resulting code, though really hard to understand, is somethimes bigger than source one.

I've heard about many good solutions (YUI from Yahoo, Clousure from Google), but they're all downloadable libraries, no on-line, one-click solution.

What I'm actually looking for is an JS minifier and obsfucator, that will minify a code (pretty like BrainJar's do) and obsfucate all variables, function names etc. to 1-2 character lengths (shortest possible). I know that this could be less secure, but due to purpose (internal project), size of the code, not security, is a key here. I also need it as one-click, on-line ready tool.

I hope that I don't set too many conditions and such tool does exists at all? :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [online version](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) of Google Closure Compiler hosted on GAE. It works very well.

Comment: Hm... Because I'm not an advanced JS developer, I used a piece of code from [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/cs/mercury-subspace/938561708) to test it. Though help claims about Simple optimization mode: "_t also performs optimizations within expressions and functions, including renaming local variables and function parameters to shorter names_", it actually DID NOT do any of obsfucation - most variables and function names were left untouched. And when I tried Advanced mode, it issued 10 warning and "compiled" 33.87KB code to... 487 bytes! Making it completely unusable, of course. LOL!

Comment: I doubt there are any safe minifiers that will do this. You can call variables using `window['variable' + i]` and reference `variable1`, `variable2`, etc. without explicitly typing out variable names. The JS minifier isn't going to touch strings, and if the minifier does, it is not safe for production use.

Comment: That being said, you could try this one. It makes the code almost unreadable: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: Yes, that looks like a solution, I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using http://smallerapp.com/ to minify my JS. It is a one click desktop solution for MAC. It uses YUI compressor to compress javascript files.

Comment: I was asking strictly about an on-line solution, not installable one.

Comment: Looks good, but seems a bit expensive (20 US$)

Answer (score 1):

I have had great luck with the online one on [www.blimptontech.com](http://www.blimptontech.com)
You can compress or combine your JS files on there. Though I have never used the combine feature. I think it uses uglify to do its magic.